# Timing parsing step of xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application and I build one of my GUIs by creating a custom data model ( Classes I have created to hold the data ) then set the datacontext of an items control that then uses a number of datatemplates and data triggers to display the data as I require.

After seeing how sluggish this is I have added some timing to the codebehind that builds the datamodel and have confirmed that this isn't what is slow.

I suspect the parsing of the xaml to build the visual tree is causing the lag.

Is there anyway of timing how long the xaml parsing is taking?

Please let me know if you require anymore information.

Comment: Can you please show the contents of your view and your datatemplates.

Comment: Not really Jordy.... I have 600+ lines of xaml defining my various data templates

Comment: Can you run profiler in VisualStudio to see which bits are causing the lag??

Comment: Krishna, this sounds like it could be useful. Never run a profiler before. Will read up on it and see what I can find.

Comment: Why not use a profiler? Something like [dotTrace](http://i.imgur.com/09S526C.png) will help you identify the slow bits of your code. (it comes with a 10 days trial)

Comment: Are you using StaticResources or DynamicResources. Using DynamicResources can be a performance hit when having a lot of controls with different templates. Because the all get loaded runtime. StaticResources are kind of loaded before the application starts. Also take a look at the debugwindow to see if there are any binding expression errors. This will also slow things down. And is it the same in release. Without the debugger on

Comment: Thanks Jordy will check that out :)

Comment: Post your current code and XAML. I'm pretty sure your performance problems are caused by not properly using UI Virtualization.